# vbs script protected view

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a set of excel files that open in protected view. I would like to open these excel files, remove the protected view, then save them as tab delimited text files. So far, I have been able to do everything but when I run the script, a prompt comes up asking if the user would like to save the excel file. I want to get rid of this prompt to make the script fully automatic. Here is the current code:

```
format = -4158

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
dest_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))

Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

oExcel.ProtectedViewWindows.Open(src_file)
oExcel.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit
oExcel.Quit

Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)
oBook.Worksheets(5).Activate

oBook.SaveAs dest_file, format

oBook.Close False

oExcel.Quit
```

I have found solutions to removing the prompt online, but because I have to edit the protected view window, I could not find a way to use the solutions. How can I make it so that this VB script removes the protected view, and saves the excel file as a tab delimited text file? It should do this without showing any windows or prompts, i.e., it should be automatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply have Excel ignore message boxes in general it is like this:

```
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
'your code here to close workbook
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: right after which part?  you could start your script with the false statement and place the true statement right before the last quit statement since you're looking for full automation anyways.

Comment: I placed this right after I initialized oExcel. But now a plethora of strange things are occuring. I am trying this on two different computers, both with 2013 Excel. On one computer, the prompt doesn't appear and I get an error saying "the server threw an exception", followed by excel crashing. On another computer, the prompt still appears and nothing changes. But a few times, the prompt would not appear, but nothing would happen! Then I would get an error saying "call rejected by callee".

Comment: is there a way to simply save the oExcel object right before the first time i call oExcel.Quit?

Comment: Why do you have `oExcel.Quit` in the middle of the script?  As a test, I copied your code and ran it without this and it worked without incident.  Also without turning off display alerts.  I'm also using Excel 2013 FYI.

Comment: Oh wow it works! The reason I had oExcel.Quit the first time is because when I did not have oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False, it was opening multiple instances of Excel and it was causing weird problems. However is does not seem that is occurring anymore. I also needed display alerts off because if the file was in protected view the vb script could not open the excel file. Anyways I will accept your answer. Thank you.